# Android Licensing DeviceId for LVL without added permissions

Tags: android, android-lvl

How do you properly construct a device Id without requiring added permissions? What rules should you follow?

This question is in reference to this [example code:](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator)

```
// Construct the LicenseChecker with a Policy.
mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
      new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
      BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY  // Your public licensing key.
      );
```

And this accompanying text:

> Before requesting new permissions for the sole purpose of acquiring
>   device-specific information for use in your Obfuscator, consider how
>   doing so might affect your application or its filtering on Google Play
>   (since some permissions can cause the SDK build tools to add the
>   associated ).

So how would one go about generating a good Id without using any permissions?

Answer (score 1):

One answer is to generate a unique application installation Id the first time an application runs. An example is provided on the [android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).